# Move nightwatch.conf.js out of root directory

Tags: node.js, nightwatch.js

I'm using nightwatch.js to run tests, and would like to declutter the root directory of my app. Is it possible for nightwatch to run with nightwatch.conf.js anywhere other than the root directory? Something like

```
App
|
 - Test
     |
      - NightwatchTests
     |
      - nightwatch.conf.js
.
.
.
```

Instead of

```
App
|
 - Test
     |
      - NightwatchTests   
.
.
.
 - nightwatch.conf.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to run my tests with `nightwatch --config PATH_TO_NIGHTWATCH_CONF`

Answer (score 1):

You can keep your nightwatch.conf.js anywhere, but remember to set absolute path for test case folder, jars, page objects etc. Try not to store nightwatch.conf.js (or nightwatch.json) file inside test case folder.

Comment: Thanks - as an alternative, you could pass to Nightwatch's `--config` option the path to `nightwatch.conf.js`